# tableview is empty but I see the data in playground coming from urlsession

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I am beginner in swift , I used url session to fill my tableview by a post request , I see data in playground but I find the tableview empty , I do not know why but the models I used are Rent and Rents

Rent model :

```
import Foundation

class Rent {
    
    var location_id: Int
    var datelocation:String
    var adresselocation: String
    var user_id: Int
    var bike_id: Int
    var model: String
    var type: String
    var price: String
    var image: String
    
    init(id: Int ,date: String , adresse: String , user: Int , bike: Int , model: String ,type:String ,price:String ,image:String ){
        self.location_id = id
        self.datelocation = date
        self.adresselocation = adresse
        self.model = model
        self.user_id = user
        self.bike_id = bike
        self.type = type
        self.price = price
        self.image = image
    }
    
}
```

I used also another model Rents:

```
import Foundation

class Rents: Codable {
    
    var location_id: Int
    var datelocation:String
    var adresselocation: String
    var user_id: Int
    var bike_id: Int
    var model: String
    var type: String
    var price: String
    var image: String 
}
```

my urlsession is post query but I retrieve all the data I need for my tableview

here my tableview code:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class rentlistViewController: UIViewController , UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{

    
    var u = ConnectedUser()
    var rents =  [Rent]()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        self.DisplayConnectedUser()
        /*DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.getRents()
        }*/
        
        //post
    
        guard let url = URL(string: "http://localhost:3000/locations") else {
        return
        }
        
        let bodyparameters = [ "user_id": self.u.user_id! , "name": self.u.name! , "lastname": self.u.lastname! , "email": self.u.email! , "password": self.u.password! , "phone": self.u.phone! ] as [String : Any]
        
       print(bodyparameters)
        
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        guard let httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: bodyparameters, options: []) else{
            print("error in sending data")
            return
            }
        request.httpBody = httpBody
        let session = URLSession.shared
        session.dataTask(with: request) { (data,response,error) in
            if let response = response {
                print(response)
            }
            
            if let data = data {
                do {
                    //let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
                   // print(json);
                    print(data)
                    let rt = try JSONDecoder().decode([Rents].self, from: data)
                
                        print(rt)
                        
                        for item in rt {
                            let id = item.location_id
                            let adresselocation = item.adresselocation
                            let datelocation = item.datelocation
                            let user = item.user_id
                            let bike = item.bike_id
                            let model = item.model
                            let type = item.type
                            let price = item.price
                            let image = item.image
                            self.rents.append(Rent(id: id ,date: datelocation, adresse: adresselocation,user: user, bike: bike,  model: model , type: type , price: price, image: image))
                        }
                        for item in self.rents {
                            print(item.location_id)
                            print(item.adresselocation)
                            print(item.datelocation)
                            print(item.user_id)
                            print(item.bike_id)
                            print(item.model)
                            print(item.type)
                            print(item.price)
                            print(item.image)
                        }
                        print(self.rents)
                        
                }catch{
                    print("error in parsing")
                    print(error)
                }
                
            }
            
        }.resume()
        
        
    }
    
    func DisplayConnectedUser() {
            
             let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
                //represente l'ORM
                let persistentContainer = appDelegate.persistentContainer
                
                let managedContext = persistentContainer.viewContext     //retourne NSManagedObject toujours
                
                //la requete retourne un NSManagedObject
                let request = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName :   "Users")
                
                //execution de la requete
                do {
                
                    let result = try  managedContext.fetch(request)
                for item in result {
                    print(item.value(forKey: "user_id") as! Int )
                    print(item.value(forKey: "email")  as! String)
                    self.u.user_id  = (item.value(forKey: "user_id")  as! Int)
                    self.u.email = (item.value(forKey: "email")  as! String)
                    self.u.password = (item.value(forKey: "password")  as! String)
                    self.u.name = (item.value(forKey: "name")  as! String)
                    self.u.lastname = (item.value(forKey: "lastname")  as! String)
                    self.u.phone = (item.value(forKey: "phone")  as! String)
                   
                    print(self.u.user_id!)
                    print(self.u.email!)
                    print(self.u.password!)
                    print(self.u.name!)
                    print(self.u.lastname!)
                    print(self.u.phone!)
                  
                }
                
                   }
                   catch {
                   print("NO DATA FOUND , Error")
                   }


        }
    
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return rents.count
    }
    
    
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellRent")
        let contentView = cell?.contentView
        let label = contentView?.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel
     
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            label.text = self.rents[indexPath.row].model
            print("heloooooo"+label.text!)
        }
            
        return cell!
    }
  
    
    //passage de parametres entre les controleurs
 
         func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            let rent = self.rents[indexPath.row]
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "mRentDetails" , sender: rent) //passage de variable locale)
            
        }
        
        /* prepare est pour passer les parametres  */
        override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?){
        
        if segue.identifier == "mRentDetails" {
        
        let rent = sender as! Rent
        let destination = segue.destination as! RentDetailsViewController
            destination.datelocation = rent.datelocation
       // destination.hours = rent
       // destination.totalprice = rent
            destination.bikemodel = rent.model
            destination.biketype = rent.type
            destination.priceperhour = rent.price
        
        }}
 
    
}
```

my problem is why if my data in the playground is displaying fully correct , why it is not displayed in my tableview?

What is wrong in my work ??? is there anyway to make the result display in my tableview ? is my tableview receiving the data late?? or is it a problem in my model class???

here everything I need to show to prove that my request works fine :

```
["email": "faresbenslama95@gmail.com", "password": "123456", "user_id": 10, "phone": "12345671", "name": "benslama", "lastname": "fares"]
<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x600003848120> { URL: http://localhost:3000/locations } { Status Code: 200, Headers {
    Connection =     (
        "keep-alive"
    );
    "Content-Length" =     (
        339
    );
    "Content-Type" =     (
        "text/html; charset=utf-8"
    );
    Date =     (
        "Mon, 14 Dec 2020 15:50:11 GMT"
    );
    Etag =     (
        "W/\"153-s80IUuqdLC0Rkz3oIqCM7x8xP7I\""
    );
    "Keep-Alive" =     (
        "timeout=5"
    );
    "X-Powered-By" =     (
        Express
    );
} }
339 bytes
[Bicycall.Rents, Bicycall.Rents]
3
Klibia
15/10/2020 15:11
10
3
Skygrey
RTT
55
bike3.png
5
toulouse
11/02/2020 11:44
10
3
Skygrey
RTT
55
bike3.png
[Bicycall.Rent, Bicycall.Rent]
10
faresbenslama95@gmail.com
10
faresbenslama95@gmail.com
123456
benslama
fares
12345671
["user_id": 10, "lastname": "fares", "email": "faresbenslama95@gmail.com", "phone": "12345671", "password": "123456", "name": "benslama"]
<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x600003854240> { URL: http://localhost:3000/locations } { Status Code: 200, Headers {
    Connection =     (
        "keep-alive"
    );
    "Content-Length" =     (
        339
    );
    "Content-Type" =     (
        "text/html; charset=utf-8"
    );
    Date =     (
        "Mon, 14 Dec 2020 15:50:15 GMT"
    );
    Etag =     (
        "W/\"153-s80IUuqdLC0Rkz3oIqCM7x8xP7I\""
    );
    "Keep-Alive" =     (
        "timeout=5"
    );
    "X-Powered-By" =     (
        Express
    );
} }
339 bytes
[Bicycall.Rents, Bicycall.Rents]
3
Klibia
15/10/2020 15:11
10
3
Skygrey
RTT
55
bike3.png
5
toulouse
11/02/2020 11:44
10
3
Skygrey
RTT
55
bike3.png
[Bicycall.Rent, Bicycall.Rent]
<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x6000038490a0> { URL: http://localhost:3000/bikes } { Status Code: 200, Headers {
    Connection =     (
        "keep-alive"
    );
    "Content-Length" =     (
        314
    );
    "Content-Type" =     (
        "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    );
    Date =     (
        "Mon, 14 Dec 2020 15:50:18 GMT"
    );
    Etag =     (
        "W/\"13a-G0h70hatF47P4CgaOr94LtJs2ug\""
    );
    "Keep-Alive" =     (
        "timeout=5"
    );
    "X-Powered-By" =     (
        Express
    );
} }
314 bytes
bike.png
http://localhost:3000/bike.png
bike2.png
http://localhost:3000/bike2.png
bike3.png
http://localhost:3000/bike3.png
bike4.png
http://localhost:3000/bike4.png
[Bicycall.Bike, Bicycall.Bike, Bicycall.Bike, Bicycall.Bike]
10
faresbenslama95@gmail.com
10
faresbenslama95@gmail.com
123456
benslama
fares
12345671
["user_id": 10, "email": "faresbenslama95@gmail.com", "lastname": "fares", "name": "benslama", "password": "123456", "phone": "12345671"]
<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x600003848300> { URL: http://localhost:3000/locations } { Status Code: 200, Headers {
    Connection =     (
        "keep-alive"
    );
    "Content-Length" =     (
        339
    );
    "Content-Type" =     (
        "text/html; charset=utf-8"
    );
    Date =     (
        "Mon, 14 Dec 2020 15:50:20 GMT"
    );
    Etag =     (
        "W/\"153-s80IUuqdLC0Rkz3oIqCM7x8xP7I\""
    );
    "Keep-Alive" =     (
        "timeout=5"
    );
    "X-Powered-By" =     (
        Express
    );
} }
339 bytes
[Bicycall.Rents, Bicycall.Rents]
3
Klibia
15/10/2020 15:11
10
3
Skygrey
RTT
55
bike3.png
5
toulouse
11/02/2020 11:44
10
3
Skygrey
RTT
55
bike3.png
[Bicycall.Rent, Bicycall.Rent]
```

Comment: After receiving the Data you have to reload the tableView. Create a @IBOutlet for your table view and yourTableView.reloadData()

Comment: http://www.thomashanning.com/uitableview-tutorial-for-beginners/ Reading this will give you an idea about what you are doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are updating the datasource(self.rents in your case) you also need to reload the tableview.

First you have to take an outlet of your tableview, then needs to set datasource and delegate to self if you haven’t set them already.

```
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!{
        didSet {
            tableView.delegate = self
            tableView.dataSource = self
        }
    }
```

Now you need to reload tableview after making changes with **self.rents**.

```
    DispatchQueue.main.async {[weak self] in
        self?.tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

Also use **[weak self]** while using urlSessionTask, otherwise it may create memory leaks.

```
        session.dataTask(with: request) {[weak self] (data,response,error) in
```

Comment: should i use the assistant in xcode to bind the whole tableview and just replace only what you told me to replace?

Comment: you will need to bind with the assistant, press control and then drag and drop the tableview.